Apache FOP service is rendering the Donut graph on pdf wrong
I am trying to create a donut graph on a page with some calculations and then downlaod it as pdf. I am using Apache Fop to downlaod the page as pdf . the gRaph rendering on the page view site is different from what is rendering on pdf.
I an using the code in xml
<fo:block text-align="center">
            <fo:instream-foreign-object>
                <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 42 42" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
                    <!-- Background circle -->
                    <circle cx="21" cy="21" r="15.915" fill="transparent" stroke="grey" stroke-width="3"></circle>

                    <!-- Donut chart segments -->
                    <circle cx="21" cy="21" r="15.915" fill="transparent" stroke="blue" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="67.3 32.7"
                            stroke-dashoffset="0"></circle>
                    <circle cx="21" cy="21" r="15.915" fill="transparent" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="20.3 79.7"
                            stroke-dashoffset="-67.3"></circle>


                    <!-- Inner circle for the donut hole -->
                    <circle cx="21" cy="21" r="10" fill="white"></circle>

                    <!-- Label inside the donut chart -->
                </svg>
            </fo:instream-foreign-object>
        </fo:block>

The graph shown is something like this


but the graph i need is
not sure why the donut borders are thick when i am downloading as pdf. can some one please help

I see the same result even with FOP 2.9 so it might be a bug/quirk in Apache FOP and/or Batik. But wait whether someone has more insight to perhaps adapt the SVG.

Using <circle cx="21" cy="21" r="15.915" fill="white"></circle> might give a better result with FOP.

Does FOP/Batik support fill="transparent"? fill="none" is always better than fill="transparent"

what about adding `stroke-width:"0" to the white filled circle? and maybe increase its radius to 14.415 (= 15.915 - (3/2)) ?

Use none instead of transparent. And now that all circles need to be transparent you can set the fill attribute on the parent element (in this case the <svg> element). It depends on the use, I guess, but if you need the diagram to have a white fill, you can set that on the "background" circle, like I did in the example, here:
<fo:block text-align="center">
  <fo:instream-foreign-object>
    <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 42 42"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" fill="none">
      <!-- Background circle -->
      <circle cx="21" cy="21" r="15.915" stroke="grey"
        stroke-width="3" fill="white" />
      <!-- Donut chart segments -->
      <circle cx="21" cy="21" r="15.915" stroke="blue"
        stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="67.3 32.7"
        stroke-dashoffset="0" />
      <circle cx="21" cy="21" r="15.915" stroke="black"
        stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="20.3 79.7"
        stroke-dashoffset="-67.3" />
    </svg>
  </fo:instream-foreign-object>
</fo:block>

